# How to disable bounding box for reference images?

Tags: 3d-view, image

I've got a few reference images I've been working from. I've manipulated them so that they're transparent except for the sketch lines (shown below) but would like to hide the bounding boxes.

[image: 3D Editor]

Checking/unchecking *Bounds* under *Object Properties* > *Viewport Display* has not done anything, and the *Display as* option doesn't apply to reference images.

Thanks for any help in advance.

[image: Viewport Display Menu]